# How to retrieve possible shell script exit codes when Executed shell script by Java DefaultExecutor & CommandLine?

Tags: java, shell, command-line, exit-code, executor

I am executing shell script using DefaultExecutor & CommandLine from Java Program.

For successful execution **receiving 0 exit value**

but in case of failure or **any other exit code (like 127,128,255 etc.)** from shell script, not receiving respective exit code instead getting IOException.

```
int iExitValue = 1;
CommandLine cmd = CommandLine.parse("sh /Users/DpakG/scripts/do_Database_Operations.sh");
DefaultExecutor oDefaultExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
oDefaultExecutor.setExitValue(0);
try {
    iExitValue = oDefaultExecutor.execute(cmd);
    log.info("Script Exit Code: " + iExitValue);
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("IOException occurred: ", e);
}
```

**Any Idea How to handle exit code to perform specific custom action?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After exploring more, I am able to figure out right answer.

For **Success** exit codes, use **setExitValues()** with int array of success codes instead of *'setExitValue()'* with single exit code as integer value.

```
int[] codes = {0,127,128};
oDefaultExecutor.setExitValues(codes);
```

Rest of the **Failure** exit codes would be captured within ExecuteException block

```
catch (ExecuteException exe) {
    iExitValue = exe.getExitValue();
    log.info("Script failed with exit code: " + iExitValue);
}
```

Complete code snippet with solution

```
int iExitValue = 1;
CommandLine cmd = CommandLine.parse("sh /Users/DpakG/scripts/do_Database_Operations.sh");
DefaultExecutor oDefaultExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
int[] successCodes = {0,127,128};
oDefaultExecutor.setExitValues(successCodes);
try {
    iExitValue = oDefaultExecutor.execute(cmd);
    log.info("Script succeeded with exit code " + iExitValue); // Either 0, 127 or 128 
} catch (ExecuteException exe) {
    iExitValue = exe.getExitValue();
    log.info("Script failed with exit code: " + iExitValue);
} catch (IOException ie) {
    log.error("IOException occurred: ", ie);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for `DefaultExecutor::execute()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/DefaultExecutor.html#execute(org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine)) says it throws

> ExecuteException - execution of subprocess failed or the subprocess returned a exit value indicating a failure

An [ExecuteException](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/ExecuteException.html) is a subclass of `IOException`, hence it getting caught by your code. If you instead try to (also) catch the correct exception, you can use its `getExitValue()` method to get the exit status.

```java
int iExitValue = 1;
CommandLine cmd = CommandLine.parse("sh /Users/DpakG/scripts/do_Database_Operations.sh");
DefaultExecutor oDefaultExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
oDefaultExecutor.setExitValue(0);
try {
    iExitValue = oDefaultExecutor.execute(cmd);
    log.info("Script succeeded with exit code " + iExitValue); // Always successful (0)
} catch (ExecuteException e) {
    log.info("Script failed with exit code " + e.getExitValue());
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("IOException occurred: ", e);
}
```

Comment: There really should be a way to differentiate "running the program failed" versus "the program exited with a failure status" and "the program was killed by a signal".

Comment: Thanks & Agree with you @Shawn. 
Also there should be way to differentiate between _Success exit codes_ & _Failure exit codes_ (including custom failure exit & system failure exit)

Looking for Way to capture success status code.
Also getExitValue() from ExecuteException is perfect workaround for sure.